# Delimiting documents with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm working on several documents that are within just a file, and before working on the documents, I need to define where one document begins and ends. For this, I am using the following regex:

```
MINISTÉRIO\sDO\sTRABALHO\sE\sEMPREGO(?:[^P]*(?:P(?!ÁG\s:\s\d+\/\d+)[^P]*)*)PÁG\s:\s\d+\/(\d+)\b(?:\D*(?:(?!\1\/\1)\d\D*)*)\1\/\1(?:[^Z]*(?:Z(?!6:\s\d+)[^Z]*)*)Z6:\s\d+
```

[Example is here](http://regexr.com/3cup1)

Is working 100%, the problem is, sometimes the text does not come this way I showed.. it comes with spaces and lines. As you can see [here](http://regexr.com/3cup4), the document is the same as the previous one, but the regular  expression does not work. I wonder why is not working and how to fix to make it work ?

Also, I need modify the regex, not the text, cause the only real part that I have access is the regex.

OBS: I'm using Node.JS, that's why i'm tagging with JS this post.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You said that you don't need modifications to the regular expression, and then you see that you do. I'm not sure that I follow. Additionally, it's not entirely clear what result you are expecting.

Comment: Sorry, this part is unclear, let me delete.. yes, i need modifications in the regular expression hahaha.

Comment: There appears to be an issue with the second `\d+`